# SAS aggregation when too many variables with different priority rules are included

Tags: sas, summarization

I have a table storing multiple lines of info for users with different `IDs`.

I would like to summarize the data into only one line of all desired info for each member. However, different rules in choosing the right value for different variables makes it hard for me.

**Example:** Original table and desired outcome for the table is listed below (only one member is shown here):

```
Name DOB Evnt1 Time1-A  Time1-B  Evnt2 Time2-A Time2-B Evnt3 Time3-A  Time3-B
JanD ABC CCC   1/1/2017 1/3/2017 .     .       .       .     .        .
JanD ABC NNN   3/3/2017 3/7/2017 .     .       .       QQQ   4/3/2017 3/5/2017
JanD ABC .     .        .        NNN   2/9/2017.       NNN   5/7/2017 4/7/2017
```

to

```
Name  DOB  Evnt1  Time1     Event2  Time2       Event3  Time3
JanD  ABC  CCC    1/3/2017  NNN     2/9/2017    QQQ     4/3/2017
```

**Rules are:**

- `Event123` has to be selected based on the priority of `CCC>QQQ>NNN`.
- `TimeAB` have to match Event and always choose the max value between `A&B`.
- Event Category overrule the max value of time.

I tried `proc` summary but it won't always have the right match between Event and max time.

Can anyone help on what aggregation method might be useful in summarizing info when too many variables are involved?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post your sample data as text within your question, not as an image.

Comment: Most likely a DATA step is going to be the easiest way to implement your rules. Another way is custom formats that will convert to the orders you need. Depending on how many variables that could get tedious fast.

Comment: @Reeza The table has 100+ variables. Can you please give an example about how it's going to work?

Comment: Post what you've tried and/or data we can work with. I'm not spending time typing out your data to generate sample data AND code.

Comment: @Reeza  I edited the table into text version, hope this is easier to work with. The original table has 100+ variables and I have tried proc summary to aggregate them into one line per member. But ID statement chose the maximum value based on the order of the listed variable so it does not apply to all events. I am still learning so don't really know which method could be the best approach here. Thanks!

Comment: Based on the rules, shouldn't the desired `Time1` be `1/*3*/2017`?

Comment: @Hugs  Yes. Thanks for pointing it out. Updated it now.